# using variables outside of completion block

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im currently retrieving data from firebase the data is put inside an `NSObject` and then a completion block. The item inside of the completion block is store as a variable `userBinfos`. Variable `userBinfos` only work inside of the completion block i want to use this outside of the completion

```
var userBinfos = userObject()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        userBinfo { (user) in
        self.userBinfos = user

        }  
//I want to use to variable here but it does not work 
        print(self.userBinfos.email)

    }


    func userBinfo(completion: (userObject) -> ()) {

        let dbFir = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        let firRef = dbFir.child("frontEnd/users/\(userId)")

        firRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

            let userDict = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
            self.name.text = userDict["firstname"] as? String
            self.userBio.text = userDict["userBio"] as! String

            var user = userObject()

            user.firstName = userDict["firstname"]
            user.lastName = userDict["lastname"]
            user.email = userDict["email"]
            user.profileImageUrl = userDict["profileImageUrl"]
            user.userBio = userDict["firstname"]
            user.userId = userDict["firstname"]

                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            completion(user)

            })

        }) { (error) in
            print(error)
        }

    }
```

Comment: you're calling  print(self.userBinfos.email) outside the block!! put it inside: userBinfo { (user) in
      } so it is being called before it is being assigned by the block

Comment: `observeEventType` works asynchronously that means the completion block is called later after `viewDidLoad` finishes. Put the code you want to execute outside the completion block in the block and you are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire purpose of the `completion` parameter of `userBinfo` is to provide a mechanism for being informed when the asynchronous `observeEventType` is called. So put code contingent upon the completion of that asynchronous method *inside* the `userBinfo { user in ... }` closure.

And if part of the UI doesn't make sense until that asynchronous `completion` closure is called, then have `viewDidLoad` configure the UI to make that explicit (perhaps show a `UIActivityIndicatorView` or whatever) and then remove that stuff inside the completion handler.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // do whatever you want to let the user know that something asynchronous
    // is happening, e.g. add a spinning `UIActivityIndicatorView` or whatever

    userBinfo { user in
        self.userBinfos = user

        // Update the UI here, including removing anything we presented to let
        // the user know that the asynchronous process was underway. If you were
        // dealing with UITableView`, you'd call `tableView.reloadData()` here.
    }  

    // but not here
}
```