# Swift : not exiting Firebase observe fuction block

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

Does not exit from the observe block.

Doesn't print hello or events.

Stuck on fetching from database.

Displays the data from Firebase but not outside the block.

For example :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    databaseRef.child("Events").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: {
        snapshot in
        print(snapshot)
        var temp : event = event()
        temp.name = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["name"] as? String ?? ""
        temp.description = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["description"] as? String ?? ""
        temp.date = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["date"] as? String ?? ""
        temp.price = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["price"] as? String ?? ""
        temp.venue = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["venue"] as? String ?? ""
        temp.genre1 = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["genre1"] as? String ?? ""
        temp.genre2 = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["genre2"] as? String ?? ""
        temp.img = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["img"] as? String ?? ""

        self.events.append(temp)
        print(self.events)
    })
    print("Hello")
    print(self.events)
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39067196/using-variables-outside-of-completion-block

Answer (score 1):

Few things here:-

- You are using, **`childAdded`** as the **FIRDataEventType**, and this query will only be fired when your *Events* node will get a value appended. If you want to access the present data in your Database node use **`value`** .

  ```
  databaseRef.child("Events").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.value, with: {
  ```
- `print(self.events)` statement outside the **`completionBlock:`** will not work since the made to firebase database are asynchronous , but only the `print(self.events)` statement inside the completionBlock is only going to work.
- If the case is that your viewDidLoad is not called then maybe you are not on the right viewController at the time.